# Lotus Notes XML Export as embedded view not working

Tags: xml, export, lotus-notes, export-to-xml

I am trying to export fields from a Lotus Notes database via XML.

I created a view with all the columns and the XML tags.
I then created a page that references this embedded view.
When I open the page in Lotus Notes it is all shown properly, but on the internet the embedded view is not shown.

I have been trying everything I thought of but was still unable to solve the issue.
We gave manager rights to anonymous, so I think we can exclude rights as an issue at this point.

What else could there be that hinders the view from showing up properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the view or the page are hidden from web? Either in the design properties or by security role

Comment: How do I find out whether or not this is the case? I compared every single checkbox with a different view that is working on a different database.

Comment: What designer version? If it is notes >8.5 in the view overview, there's a checkmark in the web column if the view is visible for the web.

Comment: Problem got solved elsewhere. View contents as HTML was not set. Works now.